# Avoid race condition when using fs.writeFileSync

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm utilising bluebird, request-promise and writeFileSync to download a png and write it to a file, my code is:`

```
function downloadPng(url) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        return request.get({
            url : url,
            headers : header,
            encoding: 'binary',
        }).then((res) => {
            fs.writeFileSync('fileName', res, 'binary')
            return foo('fileName')//my function using fileName
        }).then((resultFromFoo) => {
            resolve(resultFromFoo)        
        }).catch((error) => {
            reject(error)
        })
```

i thought using writeFileSync ensure foo will only be executed after writeFileSync succeed?  but i still get a race condition where my foo called before the file created, how i do that correctly?

Comment: Why do you create a Promise yet never call resolve or reject?

Comment: It's very strange. This code should work, and the file should be finished writing before `foo()` is called.

Comment: It is more likely that the problem is somewhere else, the code as it is shown should work, as long as `downloadPng` is not called concurrently multiple times.  Beside that it does not make sense to create a  new promise here, because `request.get` already returns a Promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more likely that the problem is somewhere else, the code as it is shown should work, as long as `downloadPng` is not called concurrently multiple times.

Beside that it does not make sense to create a  new promise here, because `request.get` already returns a Promise, and instead of `Sync` you should use a promisified version of the write command:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird')
const fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'))

function downloadPng(url) {
  return request.get({
      url: url,
      headers: header,
      encoding: 'binary',
    }).then(res => {
      return fs.writeFileAsync('fileName', res, 'binary')
    })
    .then(() => {
      return foo('fileName') //my function using fileName
    })
})
```

If you can use `await` and `async` you could write it that way:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird')
const fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'))

async function downloadPng(url) {
  var res = await request.get({
    url: url,
    headers: header,
    encoding: 'binary',
  });

  await fs.writeFileAsync('fileName', res, 'binary')

  return foo('fileName')
})
```